# How to sum the same objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

It is possible to sum the values of an array if they are the same like this:

```
var COLLECTION = [
  {
    "coords":[1335,2525],
    "items":[
      {id: "boletus",qty: 1},
      {id: "lepiota",qty: 3},
      {id: "boletus",qty: 2},
      {id: "lepiota",qty: 4},
      {id: "carbonite",qty: 4},
    ],
  },
  {
    "coords":[1532,2889],
    "items":[
      {id: "boletus",qty: 2},
      {id: "lepiota",qty: 6},
      {id: "boletus",qty: 1},
      {id: "lepiota",qty: 4},
      {id: "chamomile",qty: 4},
    ],
  }]
```

To return something like this:

```
var COLLECTION = [
  {
    "coords":[1335,2525],
    "items":[
      {id: "boletus",qty: 3},
      {id: "lepiota",qty: 7},
      {id: "carbonite",qty: 4},
    ],
  },
  {
    "coords":[1532,2889],
    "items":[
      {id: "boletus",qty: 3},
      {id: "lepiota",qty: 10},
      {id: "chamomile",qty: 4},
    ],
  }]
```

Wihout losing the other parts of the array?
(doing by hand is hard because I have more than 10 thousand duplicates like the example above, and the array have 600 thousand entries.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `map()` to create new array and inside `reduce()` to group `items` objects by id and sum qty.

```js
var data = [{"coords":[1335,2525],"items":[{"id":"boletus","qty":1},{"id":"lepiota","qty":3},{"id":"boletus","qty":2},{"id":"lepiota","qty":4},{"id":"carbonite","qty":4}]},{"coords":[1532,2889],"items":[{"id":"boletus","qty":2},{"id":"lepiota","qty":6},{"id":"boletus","qty":1},{"id":"lepiota","qty":4},{"id":"chamomile","qty":4}]}]
  
const result = data.map(function({coords, items}) {
  return {coords, items: Object.values(items.reduce(function(r, e) {
    if(!r[e.id]) r[e.id] = Object.assign({}, e)
    else r[e.id].qty += e.qty
    return r;
  }, {}))}
})  

console.log(result)
```

Comment: your result looks different than expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the functions **[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** and **[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)**

*This approach mutates the original array*

```js
var COLLECTION = [  {    "coords":[1335,2525],    "items":[      {id: "boletus",qty: 1},      {id: "lepiota",qty: 3},      {id: "boletus",qty: 2},      {id: "lepiota",qty: 4},      {id: "carbonite",qty: 4},    ],  },  {    "coords":[1532,2889],    "items":[      {id: "boletus",qty: 2},      {id: "lepiota",qty: 6},      {id: "boletus",qty: 1},      {id: "lepiota",qty: 4},      {id: "chamomile",qty: 4},    ],  }];
  
COLLECTION.forEach((o) => {
  o.items = Object.values(o.items.reduce((a, c) => {
    (a[c.id] || (a[c.id] = {id: c.id, qty: 0})).qty += c.qty;
    return a;
  }, {}));
});

console.log(COLLECTION);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**If you want to create a new array and keep the original data:**

*This approach uses the function **[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** to create a new "cloned" array.*

```js
var COLLECTION = [  {    "coords":[1335,2525],    "items":[      {id: "boletus",qty: 1},      {id: "lepiota",qty: 3},      {id: "boletus",qty: 2},      {id: "lepiota",qty: 4},      {id: "carbonite",qty: 4},    ],  },  {    "coords":[1532,2889],    "items":[      {id: "boletus",qty: 2},      {id: "lepiota",qty: 6},      {id: "boletus",qty: 1},      {id: "lepiota",qty: 4},      {id: "chamomile",qty: 4},    ] }],
    result = COLLECTION.map(o => o);

result.forEach((o) => {
  o.items = Object.values(o.items.reduce((a, c) => {
    (a[c.id] || (a[c.id] = {id: c.id, qty: 0})).qty += c.qty;
    return a;
  }, {}));
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take the power of [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and render the result by using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with a mapping function which builds new objects for `items`.

```js
var COLLECTION = [{ coords: [1335, 2525], items: [{ id: "boletus", qty: 1 }, { id: "lepiota", qty: 3 }, { id: "boletus", qty: 2 }, { id: "lepiota", qty: 4 }, { id: "carbonite", qty: 4 }], }, { coords: [1532, 2889], items: [{ id: "boletus", qty: 2 }, { id: "lepiota", qty: 6 }, { id: "boletus", qty: 1 }, { id: "lepiota", qty: 4 }, { id: "chamomile", qty: 4 }] }];

COLLECTION.forEach(o => {
    var map = new Map;
    o.items.forEach(({ id, qty }) => map.set(id, (map.get(id) || 0) + qty));
    o.items = Array.from(map, ([id, qty]) => ({ id, qty }));
});

console.log(COLLECTION);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```